# How to make mutliple times of insertAdjacentElement

Tags: javascript

How do I make multiple times of insertAdjacentElement like below?

```
test.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',elm1);
test.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',elm2);
test.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',elm3);
```

I can make a function to refactor it, but is there any shortcut to doing this? Like:
`test.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',elm1, elm2, elm3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're inserting at the end of a *container*, you can use [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), which accepts multiple arguments.

```
containerOfTest.append(elm1, elm2, elm3)
```

Otherwise, a very simple loop would do.

```
for (const elm of [elm1, elm2, elm3]) {
  test.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',elm);
}
```

Another option is to create a DocumentFragment, insert all elements into it, and then insert the fragment (only once) into the DOM.

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.test');

const elm1 = document.createElement('div');
const elm2 = document.createElement('div');
const elm3 = document.createElement('div');
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
fragment.append(elm1, elm2, elm3);
test.parentElement.insertBefore(fragment, test.nextElementSibling);

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```